# Finding dupe records, deleting them, ordering and re-numbering all record in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

The following php code finds dupe records in a database, deletes all similar records (but one of them not), re-orders all data in a cronological way and finally re-numbers progressively all rows (id field) from 1 to n.

THE PROBLEM: when i execute this code it happens that the table name "mytable" is changed in "tmp" and everything stops and goes wrong.

Why this? How can I fix the issue?

```
 $creatmp = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1 GROUP BY name, surname, birthdate"); 
 $cancqsos = mysql_query("DROP TABLE mytable"); 
 $datmpaqsos = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE tmp RENAME TO mytable"); 

 $creariordinoid = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE riordinoid LIKE mytable");
 $popolariordinoid = mysql_query("INSERT INTO riordinoid SELECT * FROM qsos ORDER BY birthdate");
 $svuotacampoid = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `riordinoid` DROP `id`");
 $ricontauno = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `riordinoid` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
 $ricontadue = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `riordinoid` ADD `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;");
 $svuotaqsos = mysql_query("DROP TABLE mytable");
 $rinominariordinoid = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE riordinoid RENAME TO mytable");
```

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Thank you so much Jason for your suggestion. At the moment I don't know MySQLi, I'm a newbie, so I'd like to fix first in MySQL and after I will modify all the code in the php file where this code stands.

Comment: Is `mytable.id` already declared `auto_increment primary key`? And what is table `qsos`?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out, would be to test the return values of all `mysql_query()`s and echo `mysql_error()` after every query.

When you know, which statement is going wrong and why, you can then decide how to fix it.

What I question upfront is, why this additional step with table `tmp`, when you replace it later with yet another table `riordinoid`.

A further observation, is that there's no point in `WHERE 1` and `ORDER BY birthdate` when copying the table.

Comment: Well, i'm open to modify all the code. Have you better and more efficient solutions? I?m enough newbie and so i trust everyone's suggestions. :)

Comment: Don't follow blindly! I've been wrong before. Test the suggestions and see if it works for you. So, as a first step, check return values and echo errors.